# How to use command blocks to make a private faction

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically I want to use a command block to tp anybody but me out of my faction upon entering.

What my command block says.

```
/testfor [r=5,Name=Gamersfunhouse]*
```

*I also have this for every other player on the server

nothing will work... I have tried to do somthing like this in it

```
/testfor [r=5,Name=<Player Name>, tp <coordinates>
```

Yet again to no avail. Please help I am sick of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` in `name` should not be capitalized; capitalization is important for selector arguments. Change that, and your original command should work.

I'd recommend using `!Gamersfunhouse`, rather than having a command block for every player. It'd also probably be easier to have the selector in a `/tp` command, seeing how you're trying to tp people away:

```
/tp @a[name=!Gamersfunhouse,r=5] X Y Z
```

Comment: Could I do more than one name in the combo like "name=<name>,<name>,etc.??/

Comment: @Gamersfunhouse No. Selecting multiple, specific players with a single target selector is probably best done via the scoreboard, by setting up an dummy objective or a team. If you want to know more about this, you can ask that as a new question.